# button will disable until all the input is not filluped is not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, button, stripe-payments

[image]

Here above is my form input filled. I create a script if input filled is fillup then button will enabled until button is disabled.

But on **Card Number** input box it is not effected with other input. without card number button shows enabled but i want it must be disabled if all filled is not fillup..

Here is my jQuery script:

```
jQuery(document).on('change keyup', '.required', function(e){
           let Disabled = true;
            jQuery(".required").each(function() {
              let values = this.value;

              if ((values)&&(values.trim() !=''))
                  {
                    Disabled = false;
                  }else{
                    Disabled = true;
                    return false;
                  }
            });
            
    
           if(Disabled){
                jQuery('#submit_button').prop("disabled", true);
              }else{
                jQuery('#submit_button').prop("disabled", false);
              }
         });
```

These card number input field is come from stripe payment api.

```
<div id="card-element" class="inputText gdcard">
         <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
</div>
```

I can't use stripe card element input field with my `.required` class. Please sort me out this bug?

Comment: you want he button pay disabled until all inputs are required, and you want card number disabled until all others are required?

Comment: and #card-number is not required?

Comment: card element is came from stripe payment js library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way to manage this is to [listen to events](https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/events) on Stripe Elements. In particular, you could listen to the `change` event on a card element ([doc](https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/events/on_change?type=cardElement)) and inspect the value of `event.complete` to see if the form is filled out. If it is (and your other fields are too) you can enable the Pay button.

```
function checkIfCardComplete(elementsEvent) {
  if (elementsEvent.complete) {
    $("#pay-now").removeAttr("disabled")
  } else {
    $("#pay-now").attr("disabled", "disabled")
  }
}

card.on('change', function(event) {
  checkIfCardComplete(event);
});
```

You can see an example implementation of this here (which only looks at the card input being complete, it ignore the other fields): https://jsfiddle.net/nolanhawkins/dhjybsnr/3/

**edit:**
If, for example, you refactored your code to make the check on your custom fields a function:

```
function areAllMyFieldsValid() {
  let Disabled = true;
  jQuery(".required").each(function() {
    let values = this.value;

    if ((values)&&(values.trim() !='')) {
     Disabled = false;
    } else {
      Disabled = true;
      return false;
    }
  });
  return !Disabled; // really you should invert your logic, not the result
}
```

then you could change the check in the event handler to just look at this additionally:

```
if (elementsEvent.complete && areAllMyFieldsValid()) { ...}
```

Comment: Thanks dear @Nolan H , problem is fixed

Comment: Quite welcome! If my answer (or any other) solves the issue for you please consider accepting the answer with the check mark :)

Comment: Dear @Nolan H these problem was fixed but when I fillup cards data button will enable automatically but my other input field is not filled up I want when all field is fillup then button will enable

Comment: Then you should track the completion state of your own form fields and check that alongside `event.complete` in the Card `change` event:  `if (elementsEvent.complete && myFieldsComplete) {...}`

Comment: Sure, done. It's just turning you code into a function to check your own field, and also using that in the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
$("#card-element").prop(disabled, true);
jQuery(document).on('change keyup', '.required', function(e) {
  //uncomment if this item has required class
  //($("#card-element").removeClass(".required"); 
  var isItOk = jQuery(".required").toArray().every((e) => $(e).val().trim() != '');
  $("#card-element").prop(disabled, isItOk);
  isItOk = isItOk && $("#card-element").val().trim() != '';

  jQuery('#submit_button').prop("disabled", isItOk);
});
```

**jQuery(".required").toArray().every((e) => $(e).val().trim() != '');** means all items which have the class `.required` are not empty

Comment: I tried this but not success. It will show disable button if my all field is filluped.